# C++ type traits to extract template parameter class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, type-traits

In a template, I want to drill down the template parameter to the real non-templated type. So:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyTemplate
{
    // sadly there's no extract_Base
    typedef typename extract_base<T>::MyType WorkType;
};
struct X {};
template <typename T> struct Templ {};
//MyTemplate<Templ<X>>::WorkType is X;
//MyTemplate<X>::WorkType is X;
```

The only solution I see is to define real base type like std::vector<X>::value_type is X. But I am curious if there's a way to do this without defining auxiliary types inside each destination template.

I saw something like http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2965.html but this is draft? and I don't quite get it.

Yes I know there's multiple inheritance, but even for simple case this would be nice.

UPDATE: Nawaz solution works for me very well, and it is easy to extend to specific cases, e.g.

```
template<template<typename, typename> class X, typename T1, typename T2>
struct extract_base <X<T1, T2>>   //specialization
{
    typedef T1 base;
};
```

I can even apply is_base_of or other filters to T1/T2 and so on. So it *does* work for X<T,U> - at least with g++ 4.6.7.

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance or base classes.

Comment: There is `std::is_base_of` but that may not suit your purposes entirely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, let's call it `value_type` instead of `base`, because `value_type` seems to be more appropriate term to describe the type which you want to extract.

You can use this:

```
template<typename T>
struct extract_value_type //lets call it extract_value_type
{
    typedef T value_type;
};

template<template<typename> class X, typename T>
struct extract_value_type<X<T>>   //specialization
{
    typedef T value_type;
};
```

It should work as long as the template argument to `extract_value_type` is of the form of either `T` or `X<T>`. It will not work for `X<T,U>`, however. But then it is easy to implement it in C++11 using variadic template.

Use it as:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyTemplate
{
    typedef typename extract_value_type<T>::value_type value_type;
};
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/mbyvj

---

Now in C++11, you can use variadic template to make `extract_value_type` work with class templates which take more than one template arguments, such as `std::vector`, `std::set`, `std::list` etc.

```
template<template<typename, typename ...> class X, typename T, typename ...Args>
struct extract_value_type<X<T, Args...>>   //specialization
{
    typedef T value_type;
};
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/SDEgq

Comment: Compiles with "template<typename> class X" and does work! Thanks.

Comment: @queen3: Now see the variadic solution.

Comment: Yes, though X<T,U> worked for me, see update. Nevertheless that was what I needed.

Comment: @queen3: I renamed the struct name and the nested type. See it now. `value_type` suits more than `base`.

Comment: Well, in my case it is template X<T>: public T so it is really the base.

Comment: @queen3: Ohh.. I see. In that case, `std::is_base_of` can also help.

Comment: And I need "typedef typename extract_base<T1>::base base;" for a recursive trip to the deep base... oh my.

Comment: is_base_of won't help since I don't know specific types at all. I just need any first non-templated type.

Comment: @queen3: Alright. Hope my answer helps you solve your real problem.