# Given a templated class, is there a way to get the "base"/untemplated type?

Tags: c++

Pretty straightforward, but maybe not possible: Given some `T<some_type>`, is there a way to get `T`? A better example with code here:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct parametrized_class{
   
};

template<class T>
using make_floaty = T<float>; // this doesn't compile since T is not the "base" type

int main() {
   using int_class = parametrized_class<int>;
   using float_class = make_floaty<int_class>;
}
```

I don't think it is, but I want to make sure.

Comment: [Is this what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056714/c-type-traits-to-extract-template-parameter-class)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely can, although templates not being first-class citizens makes it a bit tricky:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct make_floaty;

template <template <class> class Template, class T>
struct make_floaty<Template<T>> {
    using type = Template<float>;
};

template <class T>
using make_floaty_t = typename make_floaty<T>::type;
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UImv3Yt9wIR48wF9)

Comment: Obvious extension: `template <class To, template <class> class Template, class From> struct rebind<To, Template<From>> { using type = Template<To>; };`

Answer (score 0):

By using template template parameters you can write a trait that given an instantiation of a template and another type it "returns" an instantiation with that other type:

```
template <typename OLDINSTANTIATION,typename NEWPARAMETER>
struct replace_template_parameter;

template <template<typename...> class T,typename OLDPARAM,typename NEWPARAM>
struct replace_template_parameter< T<OLDPARAM>,NEWPARAM> {
    using type = T<NEWPARAM>;
};
```

`make_floaty` can then be written as:

```
template <class T>
using make_floaty = typename replace_template_parameter< T,float>::type;
```

[Complete Example](https://godbolt.org/z/9PfzE5cas):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T> struct parametrized_class{};

template <typename OLDINSTANTIATION,typename NEWPARAMETER> struct replace_template_parameter;

template <template<typename...> class T,typename OLDPARAM,typename NEWPARAM>
struct replace_template_parameter< T<OLDPARAM>,NEWPARAM> {
    using type = T<NEWPARAM>;
};

template <class T> using make_floaty = typename replace_template_parameter< T,float>::type;

int main() {
   using int_class = parametrized_class<int>;
   using float_class = make_floaty<int_class>;
   std::cout << std::is_same< float_class, parametrized_class<float>>::value;
}
```